# How to debug angular 13 library?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I created a new angular 13 library and I having issues with it. So trying to debug it. I followed steps in existing angular library questions which mentioned to update angular json like

```
{
  "projects": {
    "your-app": {
      "architect": {
        "serve": {
          "options": {
            "vendorSourceMap": true
```

But still i am not able to use the firefox dev tools to debug the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using angular version 12 or greater the `vendorSource` would be deprecated and instead have to add `sourceMap` with `scripts`, `styles`, `vendor` as true in the build options of host applications' `angular.json`

```
{
  "projects": {
    "your-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "sourceMap": {
              "scripts": true,
              "styles": true,
              "vendor": true
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work for me using Angular 14.2.7.  The following does work, however...

```
{
  "projects": {
    "your-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "sourceMap": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": true,
                "vendor": true
              }
            }
```